# How to dust a TV screen?

Tags: technology, glass, dust

I attempted to dust the screen of my tv with a cotton cloth and much dust collected in the edges and corners. How can I dust more efficiently as to avoid this build-up?

Comment: **<comments removed>**  Folks, if you have an answer, please post it as an answer below. Comments do not have the features to properly host and vet this content. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For things within arms reach I use a swifter duster. It's cheap, disposable, and works as advertised.

Comment: Product recommendations are not hacks because they do not use everyday objects.

Comment: @Mooseman fair, however some of us would consider dusters "everyday [household] objects."

Comment: Dusters are, yes, but you are recommending a specific product.

Comment: @Mooseman "*Product recommendations are not hacks because they do not use everyday objects.*" Translation: The best solution to a problem is not welcome on this site if it is not a "hack". Low quality solutions only.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Vacuum Brush Attachment]

Most vacuum cleaners have a brush attachment. I've used several of them directly on a TV screen and haven't noticed any ill effects on the screen. It works well because you can brush the edges and corners and the vacuum sucks up the dust rather than it going into the air.

Comment: You can most certainly scratch the plastic on the screen or the bezel depending on the material that the screen and brush is made out of.

Comment: Definitely a "no, no". If TV were a sentient being it would scream out for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cloth designed to hold dust, such as micro-fiber. Generally, if you aren't using the right tools for the job, your results will be less than ideal. Flat cotton cloth does not hold dust well. Micro-fiber cloths are designed specifically for this.

[image: Boom, life hack.]

For the total package: [LCD screen cleaning kits on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lcd+cleaner&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Alcd+cleaner), [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=lcd+screen+cleaning+kit&N=-1&isNodeId=1), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=lcd+screen+cleaning+kit&tbm=shop).

There are other tools designed for removing dust as well, such as [feather dusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feather_duster):

[image]

You could "hack" it by using other various cloth and brush-like objects that do a poorer job than things actually designed for cleaning, but it would be better to use proper cleaning products.